# How to get text between two divs in ruby nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, loops, xpath, nokogiri

I want to parse the text, that is between two horizontal_lines .

It should be the text between the first and the second of this horizontal line.

I would like to use the ruby gem 'nokogiri', not necessarily by using xpath.

```
url = "http://calendar.rop.ru/?idd=167"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url), nil, 'utf-8' )
```

My(failing)try:

I thought of an iteration to find the first ant the second line in the div  with the id="block777"

```
i=2 # because from then on the 1.st line starts 
until /src=\"img\/line.gif\"/ =~ extract 
i += 1; extract = page.xpath('//div[@id="block777"]/div[position()='+i.to_s+']').inner_html` 
puts extract
```

some more aspects:

- the link to the site: [Православный календарь 2016](http://calendar.rop.ru/?idd=167)
- the interesting part(I want to get) of the page is in the `div` with the `id="block777"`
- a horizontal_line is in this html text:

`<div style="border:0px solid silver; width:100%; height:10px; margin:2px;"><img src="img/line.gif" style="width:100%; height:1px; margin-top:4px;"></div>`

- I would like to Iterate through the page and then to get the content, till I reach the next horizontal_line.

Comment: Please include text as text rather than images.  If the text would be too long, then figure out what minimal subset of the text is needed and include that.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". Images don't help us unless the question is about graphics. For source and data we need the minimal code and minimal data that demonstrate the problem, along with your desired output, all in the question, not as a link or an image. We can't reuse images and can't search on them, and have to retype code or data presented as images, which wastes our time and delays answers to you. And, honestly, a lot of potential answerers won't even try to help if you use images.

Comment: @theTinMan, thanks for your comment, ok i will try to do so in my next questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
between = doc.at('#block777').children
    .drop_while { |each| each.to_s !~ /line.gif/ }
    .drop(1) 
    .take_while { |each| each.to_s !~ /line.gif/ }
```

This skips children until the first line is found, and then skips that line, and then gets all children until another lines is found.